# javascript alert function strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, jsbin

So I am learning JavaScript.... I have gone way past this basic stuff in my learning but can't figure out why this wont work:

```
   function message(){
      alert("message"); 
    }

<button onclick="message()">Click me</button>
```

On Js Bin all is ok http://jsbin.com/uwutut/1/edit

On Js fiddle the alert is not triggered!! http://jsfiddle.net/vincentieo/D2dxA/

It is the exact same code...copy and paste so no reason why js fiddle is being fussy??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jsfiddle infrastructure puts your code in an event handler for the "load" event if you don't tell it not to. That means that your function is a local function to that handler, so it's not visible globally.

On the left side of the jsfiddle UI, look for a pull-down about where the code goes, and choose "no-wrap (body)".  See if that helps.

Comment: alternatively: `window.message = function(){ alert("message"); };`

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense...so jsfiddle is a little more customizable to our needs.  That really cleared it up

Answer (score 0):

it works perfectly if you move your javascript to your header

http://jsfiddle.net/D2dxA/2/

```
<head>
<script>
function message(){
  alert("message"); 
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: That function does not require the DOM. The problem was scoping. Wrapping the code in an `onload` callback didn't expose it to the global scope where he was attempting to call it from.

Comment: Right got it.... assumed jsfiddle would sort that out for me.

THANKS for the replies

Comment: any good tutorials for learning object orientated programming with js??

Comment: @vincentieo try [eloquent javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html)